# Creating a graph with soft edges on Windows Phone 7

Tags: c#, .net, silverlight, windows-phone-7, graph

I am trying to draw a graph in my Windows Phone 7 app. The problem I am facing is that the graph has sharp edges, but I am required to have a graph with soft edges.

I am using following code to make the edges soft:

```
Polyline chartPolyline = new Polyline();
chartPolyline.Points = graphPointsCollection; // graphPointsCollection is collection of points
chartPolyline.Stroke = borderBrush;
chartPolyline.StrokeThickness = 3;
chartPolyline.StrokeLineJoin = PenLineJoin.Round;
chartPolyline.StrokeDashCap = PenLineCap.Round;
chartPolyline.StrokeStartLineCap = PenLineCap.Round;
chartPolyline.StrokeEndLineCap = PenLineCap.Round;
```

But the output still has sharp edges. Where am I going wrong?

Comment: any response?... i am really stuck in it.

Comment: There is an output image from your code (but with thickness 9): http://s1.ipicture.ru/uploads/20111203/RwWJqj65.png. I see soft edges. What do you want to achieve?

Comment: Thanks Ku6opr for trying out the code, my problem is with the angles, all are "angular" :) i want to have curves where the line is bending. i mean a slight curve will be fine..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For smooth curves you can use, for example, Bezier curve:

```
        string PathFormatter = "<PathGeometry xmlns=\"http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation\"> "
            + "<PathGeometry.Figures>"
            + "<PathFigure StartPoint=\"{0},{1}\">"
            + "<PathFigure.Segments>"
            + "<PathSegmentCollection>"
            + "<BezierSegment Point1=\"{2},{3}\" Point2=\"{4},{5}\" Point3=\"{6},{7}\" />"
            + "</PathSegmentCollection>"
            + "</PathFigure.Segments>"
            + "</PathFigure>"
            + "</PathGeometry.Figures>"
            + "</PathGeometry>";

        double p1x = x1 * 0.67 + x2 * 0.33;
        double p1y = y1;
        double p2x = x1 * 0.33 + x2 * 0.67;
        double p2y = y2;
        string data = String.Format(PathFormatter, x1, y1, p1x, p1y, p2x, p2y, x2, y2);

        Graphic.Children.Add(new Path()
        {
            Data = (PathGeometry)XamlReader.Load(data),
            Stroke = new SolidColorBrush(color),
            StrokeThickness = 4,
            VerticalAlignment = System.Windows.VerticalAlignment.Bottom,
            Height = 368,
            CacheMode = new BitmapCache(),
            //Margin = new Thickness(0, 0, 0, 0),
            HorizontalAlignment = System.Windows.HorizontalAlignment.Left
        });
```